# Find Windows DLLs not compiled with SafeSEH

Tags: windows, dll, portable-executable

I'd like to find out which of the DLLs located in various of my installed softwares have been compiled with SafeSEH and which ones haven't. Is there a tool that could give me that information, otherwise what would be the best solution to code something that does that verification?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need to do it programmatically, parse the PE format, look through the directory entries, check if the exception directory has an RVA of 0. If it does, there's no SafeSEH.

Answer (score 1):

You could start out by taking this tool, [SafeSEH Dump](http://www.hackerscenter.com/index.php?/Downloads/View-document-details/3036-Safeseh-Dump-05.30.07.html) and examine the output. It shouldn't be too hard to run it batch-like against a list of all your DLLs. You need to create a login to download it. Here's [a blog post](http://www.mymegafiles.com/2009/07/safeseh-dump.html) that references SafeSEH Dump too, but the download link at that page seems dead.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use dumpbin.exe /loadconfig to look for the presence of the Safe Exception Handler table. More info here: http://www.jwsecure.com/dan/2007/07/06/the-safe-exception-handler-table/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an ancient question that I'm dredging up from the dead, but there *is* a programmatic solution.

First, parse the PE format. There are all sorts of solutions for this, so I won't go into it. Suffice to say that it's a bigger topic than I can cover here. If you decide to roll your own, be careful of the differences between 32-bit and 64-bit executables.

Once you've got a PE file parsed, skip the DOS header, NT signature, file header (a.k.a. COFF header),  the optional header, and finally get to the Data Directories. Each of these directories has an RVA and a size. Find the RVA and size of the Configuration Directory (the 10th entry in the list).

Here's where we can start doing detection. If the RVA or size is zero, SafeSEH isn't enabled. If the size is anything other than 0x40, it was built with a compiler that was (probably) vulnerable to the [MS12-001 SafeSEH bypass bug](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms12-001.aspx). Don't trust the size value though - it *does not necessarily match* up to the size of the data within, because of some quirks with Windows XP - see the previous link for more details.

If the RVA and size seem sensible, follow the RVA to the [Load Configuration structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Parse that, then read the `SEHandlerTable` and `SEHandlerCount` values. If the handler table pointer is null (i.e. zero) then SafeSEH is not enabled. If the handler count is zero, there are no handlers registered, even though SafeSEH might be switched on.